# Issue retrieving UserID inside SignalR hub

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I had my SignalR private chat system working when it was forcing client updates for every client connected but I wanted to streamline this so only update specific connected users when they specifically receive new messages. Using the posted "Mapping SignalR users to connections" on msdn I set everything up and it logs and changes connection IDs and users but as soon as I want to retrieve their assoicated UserID for my Sql query I get Null?

As stated above, the query worked fine when I was using HTTPContext.User.Identity.GetUserId() to retrieve the users GUID but now I have updated the code I can no longer get the currently connected UsersID no matter what I do. Even though the associated database functions have NO issue retrieving the current users UserName...

```cs
public override Task OnConnected()
{
var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
who = Context.User.Identity.Name;
UserID = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId();
.....
}

string query = "SELECT msgTo, msgFrom, msgContent, date FROM [dbo].[messages] WHERE msgTo = @id";
connection.Open();
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", UserID);
try
{
  ...
}
```

The parameterized query '(@id nvarchar(4000))SELECT  msgTo, msgFrom, msgContent, date FRO' expects the parameter '@id', which was not supplied.

Comment: so, your `Context.User.Identity.GetUserId()` return `null` right? What is in your `Context.User.Identity` then?

Comment: Context.User.Identity is System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity

Comment: I have found the cause of the issue; Upon initial connection the UserId is retrieved fine, but if a message is received then the userid cannot be retrieved. I recall reading something about the fact that asp.net doesn't sent the user information with every single request(which makes sense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by sending a querystring with each request($.connection.hub.qs = { userId: document.getElementById("usrid").value};) and then retrieving it in the hub update function